# Does StandardWrapperValve create new instances of servlets?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I am studying the following diagram:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/architecture/requestProcess/request-process.png

And I have the following question: is StandardWrapperValve in charge of creating new instances of servlets?

If I wanted to intercept servlet instance(s) prior to service, am I looking the right place?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the source code for this class in 8.5. It has comments and logic that seem to confirm this.

Source file is in folder org.apache.catalina.core.